# Python iterate from a dictionary with two values

Tags: python

I have the following python dictionary,

`dict1 = {'fabric_ssh_hosts': ['192.168.3.44 192.168.3.45 192.168.3.46']}`

How can I iterate, to produce the following output?

`192.168.3.44`

`192.168.3.45`

`192.168.3.46`

Comment: is that a list with a single item or did you mean each address to be a separate item in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect something went wrong with your code.
Why would you put all adresses in just one string and then put that into a list inside a dictionary?

In case you really mean what you wrote something like that should work

```
dict1 = {'fabric_ssh_hosts': ['192.168.3.44 192.168.3.45 192.168.3.46']}

addrstring = dict1['fabric_ssh_hosts'][0]
for addr in addrstring.split():
    print(addr)
```

In case you meant what I think you meant to do or say:

```
dict1 = {'fabric_ssh_hosts': ['192.168.3.44', '192.168.3.45', '192.168.3.46']}
for addr in dict1['fabric_ssh_hosts']:
    print(addr)
```

look closely at what is different in the dictionary thoug.

split() splits a string at whitespaces (or at other characters if you want, look into the documentation) and outputs the single words into a list:

```
"foo bar baz".split()
```

gives

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: just saw the answer from @Skyler a little to late, but maybe my remarks can help you understand what is going on

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @cmmnn Actually as you said the code is tricky but you code works! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Splitting one string is possible, but if you get the input out of a piece of code you can change I would change it if I was in your place. This would make the code more logical and easier to expand on in my opinion. On the other hand 'never change a running system' is a motto many people choose to go by.

Answer (score 4):

```
for host in dict1['fabric_ssh_hosts'][0].split():
    print host
```

Explanation: split(), when called with no arguments, splits on whitespace. dict1['fabric_ssh_hosts'] is a list, so [0] gets the first (and only) element of it. So that creates the list, which is iterated through.

Comment: I do not think it will work, as `dict1['fabric_ssh_hosts']` is a list and not a string.

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @Skyler